# How can I run an autosys job without running dependents?

Tags: scheduling, autosys

I wish to make a change to an autosys job. After I make the change:

1. I want to test it by running it in isolation **without running any dependents**.
2. After I have finished testing, I want it to be in a "normal" state; i.e. so that it (and its dependents) run automatically as usual the next day.

This seems like a pretty elementary requirement for a scheduling system.

Realistically the only way to satisfy #1 seems to be to put the dependents ON_HOLD for the duration of the test.

The trouble is that when I take them off hold at the end (for #2), they will immediately check their conditions and run - this violates requirement #1.

I could instead try satisfying condition #2 by setting them to INACTIVE, but I'm told that doing so immediately sets the *box* such a job may be in to SUCCESS - which presumably may again trigger dependents, violating #1.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set all the dependents to SUCCESS before running the job.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't prevent them from running? It seems that as soon as that dependents' dependencies are changed (such that the dependents' condition is met), they run again.

Comment: A job in Success does not start again, even if one of its preconditions goes from False to True.  What does make jobs eligible to start again is if they are bumped out of Success in some fashion, typically because a containing box is restarted; or if a date condition goes from False to True.

Comment: Finally got the chance to actually try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run job manually, you send FORCE_START event to that job. It ignores dependencies. Job will be started and after done set to SUCCESS or FAILURE.

If for your testing you want your job to be triggered automatically, then indeed condition of this job must be met.

Answer (score 0):

You may always FORCE_START job/box. That ignores dependencies for the job/box- it will just start.

If you want to test scheduled run (and ignore dependencies) putting dependencies ON_HOLD will not help you. Job that has dependencies on ON_HOLD job will wait for dependencies to be met.

Putting dependencies ON_ICE is correct way. ON_ICE dependencies are ignored.
Also, putting iced job OFF_ICE will not start them immediately-they will wait for next scheduled run.

Comment: The question is about dependents, not dependencies.